# How can KeyCloak in Kubernetes handle 200 connections?

Tags: java, kubernetes, keycloak

I am using KeyCloak helm deployment on Kubernetes. When I do a load test for 200 connections, the KeyCloak process dies.

In the `kubectl` log I see the following message:

```
*** JBossAS process (290) received TERM signal ***
```

Do you have an idea how to increase max-con-pool in standalone.xml file with helm deployment parameters?

I have checked PostgreSQL connection in DB level it is OK.

Comment: Check Kubernetes resources for the Keycloak pod, it looks like Keycloak has exhausted its resource limits and got killed.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Already done the nodes level, as well as pod level. It has free memory, CPU, keycloak has enough free virtual memory. I checked postgres connection limit in DB level. Those are OK. 
I couldn't do to increase con-max-pool in keycloak level. Anyone has idea how to increase max-con-pool using helm keycloak deployment.

Comment: How did you do you load testing? What tool did you use?